# AWS EB EnvironmentHealth Monitoring Components

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, health-monitoring

I have a few elastic beanstalk components being monitored and I occasionally get the EnvironmentHealth alerts. When I get that alert, how do I figure out what was the root cause of the alert? In other words what triggered the alert. I tired looking through this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-health.html. Couldn't figure out.

Comment: EB can report false alarms. Have you confirmed that your website was down or it was not working?

Comment: Folks who are on call always get to the alarm an hour later and find everything is ok. So I am trying to find out what are the metrics used to compute the EnvironmentHealth and with that figure out what might be causing these intermittent alerts

Comment: [EB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced.html#health-enhanced.rules) write "Elastic Beanstalk enhanced health reporting relies on a set of rules to determine the health of your environment. Some of these rules **might not be appropriate** for your particular application. " Thus, if you can't identify anything wrong with your app, maybe your app is OK, and you need to tweak these default health checks, to suite your application.